# How to draw a figure with a discrete colormap in rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I would like to draw a figure with a discrete colormap using rmarkdown.

I tried using pgfplots. The following code should give my a figure with a discrete colormap instead of a continous one. Using the same code in Latex works as expected.

In the [attached log file](https://pastebin.com/HVVBSsWW), I didn't find any clues as to what is going wrong. But I am also not sure what to look for, since there are no errors. Note that I included the undefined control sequence at the end on purpose to cause an error. Otherwise the log file is deleted right after compilation.

[figure with continous colorbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/657qS.png)

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}


---

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=-2:2,
  view={0}{90},
  colormap={CM}{
  samples of colormap=(13 of hot)},
  colormap access=piecewise constant,
  colorbar right,
  colorbar style={%
     ytick=data,
  }  
]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp]
{exp(-x^2-y^2)*x+0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Can you show your .log file? I get a discrete colourmap with the code from your question https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN41f.png

Comment: I added a link to the log file above.

Comment: You get an error "! Undefined control sequence.
l.87 \test" which I can't reproduce with the code from your question.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. As I said above, without an error, the logfile get deleted right after compilation. In order to keep it I caused the error in purpose. Not the cleanest way, but I didnt find a proper solution. The code above does not trigger the error because the undefined control sequence at the end is missing. But the logfile should look the same, except for the error of course.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that! I should have read your edit more carefully!